# How to convert MongoDB Objectid (as string) to MongoDB Object id to retrieve document from database

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

In my PHP web application I'm using MongoDB as back end storage system, in which I'm sending the document id assigned by MongoDB from one page to another via page url like:

```
www.doc.php?id='.urlencode($_id)
```

When I access the parameter from the new page it is in string format as `"ObjectId('50a8240b927d5d8b5891743f')"`. How can I convert the string into a MongoDB Object _id format so that i can access the document from the database by using `find(array('_id' => $id))`?

Comment: I improved the formatting to make the question easier to read

Answer (score 0):

Please try maybe:

```
'www.doc.php?id='.urlencode($_id->{'$id'})
```

and on the new page something like:

```
if( ! empty($_GET["id"])) {    
    $objID = new MongoId(urldecode($_GET["id"]));
}
```

On **[this site](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php)** you could find hopefully useful information on PHP MongoId.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = new \MongoId($yourObjectId);
```